# Infinitely many primes such that n is not a square mod p

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer that is not square. I want to prove there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $n$ is not a square mod $p$. I am struggling with this. I would appreciate a small hint (preferably not a full solution at first please)

Comment: Are you familiar with quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yes! I have tried using this...

Comment: So I tried splitting up $n$ as a product of primes, then I apply QR to get a product of $\pm (\frac{p}{q_i})$ where the $q_i$ are the primes with odd power, of which at least one must exist.

Comment: I see that Dirichlet's theorem would make this easier but I feel like this is cheating and that there should be a straightforward way.

Comment: Also the $\pm$ is annoying me.

Comment: It is of course natural to think of the quadratic reciprocity law, but I agree with you that the $\pm$ sign could be annoying, and besides, the Jacobi symbol $(\frac pn)$ could be $1$ without $p$ being a square mod $n$. I suggest to switch more firmly to the $p$-adic point of view, i.e. to work in the ring (resp. field) $\mathbf Z_p$ (resp. $\mathbf Q_p$) of $p$-adic integers (rep. numbers), not only in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z = \mathbf F_p$. According to your wish, I give only a first hint.

Comment: Because we are interested in producing an infinite number of primes $p$ with the adequate property, we can exclude a finite number of $p$, here exclude all the prime divisors of the given $n$. This means that we work only in a ring $\mathbf Z_p$ in which $n$ is a $p$-adic unit.  The multiplicative group $U$of $p$-adic units can be written $U=V \times U_1$, where $V\cong \mathbf F^*_p$ canonically (Hensel's lemma) and $U_1=1+p\mathbf Z_p$; moreover, if $p\neq 2$, all elements of $U_1$ are squares (why ?).

Comment: It follows that $n$ is a square mod $p$ iff $n$ is a square in $V$ (this is stronger than the classical Euler criterion). To go further, take a look at the reltionship between global and local squares (a particular case of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem).